# C++ undeclared identifier - error C2065

Tags: c++

This is most likely a simple mistake, but I just need to know what to define `colour` as and how to do it in this program. (I've created a `colour.h` file, and placed it into the Source Files folder, but written nothing in it yet.)

The error states that `error C2065: 'colour': undeclared identifier`

here is the section of code in which the error is occurring:

```
enum class traffic_light { green, yellow, red };
traffic_light light = traffic_light::red;


traffic_light& operator++(traffic_light &colour);

    switch (colour) {
    case traffic_light::green:{
                                  cout << "green\n";
                                  return colour = traffic_light::yellow;
    }
    case traffic_light::yellow: {
                                    cout << "yellow\n";
                                    return colour = traffic_light::red;
    }
    case traffic_light::red:{
                                cout << "red\n";
                                return colour = traffic_light::green;
    }
}

traffic_light next = ++light;
    cout << " << next << \n";
}
```

the error occurs at line 13: `switch (colour) {`

EDIT: the semicolon after traffic_light& operator++(traffic_light &colour); is required, as the piece of code is part of main(). Removing main, means the semicolon is not required, however gives a Linker error.

Comment: do you not need to **break;** after each case in your switch statement?

Comment: @jbutler483: `return` does the job pretty well...

Comment: And line 13 is what?

Comment: You have a semicolon after the method's signature, probably instead of an opening brace. Should be: `traffic_light& operator++(traffic_light &colour) {`, with the brace preferably in the following line (but this is of course subjective ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing off your method with the ;
It's easier to program if you let indentation help you

```
traffic_light& operator++(traffic_light &colour)//;<-- THIS was the real culprit
{ //<-- and now the switch is a part of the operator function body
    switch (colour) {
        case traffic_light::green: {
            cout << "green\n";
            return colour = traffic_light::yellow;
        }
        case traffic_light::yellow: {
            cout << "yellow\n";
            return colour = traffic_light::red;
        }
        case traffic_light::red: {
            cout << "red\n";
            return colour = traffic_light::green;
        }
    }
    // also, what do you intend with the following?
    /*traffic_light next = ++light;
    cout << " << next << \n";*/
    // if we got here there's an error, maybe a new light type?
    // return red to be safe
    return colour = traffic_light::red;
}
```

Comment: @EattomuchBread I am afraid you did not get his point. Your switch statement is "hanging loose", it should be within the method.